# Creating zoom functionality in android drawable that lies inside image-view

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-drawable

I am trying to follow the tutorial from ***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2ls3FTPOAc*** in order to zoom into my drawable which lies inside an imageview.

I see here that the scaleListener object is called since the Log outputs that it's being called. However, when I use the ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX scale type for the image-view it doesn't seem to work. I've also added a slight modification in the onScale method. Here's my code:

```
view1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX); //using CENTER works
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
view1.setImageMatrix(matrix);
DummyDraw drawD = new DummyDraw(this);
view1.setImageDrawable(drawD);

scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
```

a few methods down I have:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
return true; }

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
Log.d("inside1044","inside scale listener onSscale method ");
        float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor,5.0f));
        scaleFactor2 = scaleFactor;//a modification I made
        matrix.setScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
view1.invalidateDrawable(view1.getDrawable());//this is the modification I made
        return true;}
}
```

Now, the DummyDraw class extends Drawable which just draws a pink background and a circle in the middle of the canvas. the variable scaleFactor2 is static and defined in the MainActivity, so everytime the user touches the view the method onScale is called updating the new value for scaleFactor2. I use this scaleFactor2 value somehow to try to scale the canvas of my drawable object. Here's what the code looks like inside the drawable object, inside the onDraw():

```
//define some variables to get the center of the canvas
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(MainActivity.scaleFactor2,MainActivity.scaleFactor2);
//draw the circle to the screen
canvas.restore();
```

When I place both fingers on the screen and bring them closer together the circle jumps and moves slightly, however when I move the fingers apart nothing happens. Remember, that this works only when the ImageView.ScaleType is set to CENTER not to MATRIX.

I am trying to accomplish a smooth zoom in and out of the view.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @pskink This is what I am trying to work on now. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/0e319c80928f202b6526069f2e8795d5

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to incorporate it.

Comment: of course inside `onChange(Matrix matrix)` just call `setImageMatrix(matrix)`, thats all

Comment: Okay I see this class is somewhat like implementing a DialogInterface in Android. I see you have an interface that will be used to communicate with the MainActivity. I already incorporated the class inside my MainActivity and implemented the interface method onChange(). Now, I just must create the MatrixGestureDetector object with the required params and add setImageMatrix(matrix) and it should work. @pskink

Comment: and of course feed it with events inside `onTouchEvent`

Comment: my MatrixGestureDetector object is called mgDetect. I will feed it inside onTouchEvent with the call:  mgDetect.onTouchEvent(ev); @pskink

Comment: good, it should work

Comment: haha. Lets see, give me about 9 min. Still trying to create the mgDetect object and add the last details. @pskink

Comment: the app compiled, but the zoom functionality is not there? @pskink

Comment: is `onChange` called? add some `Log.d(TAG, "matrix " + matrix);` inside

Comment: I just set up a Log call inside.. re-compiling now. @pskink

Comment: yes is being called. @pskink

Comment: does matrix changes?

Comment: how should I detect that? by placing a Log call inside onChange? @pskink

Comment: How will this invalidate the drawable though. If there's no call to invalidate it? @pskink

Comment: it invalidates `ImageView` - inside `setImageMatrix`

Comment: So, this will invalidate the size of the image-view not the drawable inside the image-view? @pskink

Comment: It should invalidate the drawable, according to the docs. I found a way to see if the matrix values are changing. @pskink

Comment: if the matrix changes then calling `setImageMatrix` will move/zoom your drawable - of course `scaleType` must be `"matrix"`

Comment: I see that you have a return of false for onDown inside the MatrixGestureDetector, what gestures do you support inside the class? @pskink

Comment: those where `onChange` is called

Comment: I will look at this tomorrow. Thanks for the tips. @pskink

Comment: I never got it to work. I did find another way that is working how it is intended to? The drawable inside the imageview is being scaled as the user pinch zooms into the view. @pskink

Comment: Thanks for all the help though. If you want me to try to make modifications let me know though. @pskink

Comment: i have no ide how you could call `setImageMatrix` inside `onChange(Matrix matrix)` method and yet you see no scrolling / scaling, it cannot be more simple than those 20 something lines of code: https://pastebin.com/raw/YD3WK0QQ

Comment: Your set up seems different than my set up.  I will try your set up and let you know. The way I found for it to work was without relying on setImageMatrix(), just relying on invalidating the drawable inside the Image-View. I will post this way that I found and modified to my needs later, and will try your way, as well. @pskink

Comment: where did you call `setImageMatrix` in your case? you said you did it inside `onChange` didn't you?

Comment: yes I did. it was called inide onChange() and I verified onChange was being called with the Logs. So, the set up was correct. @pskink

Comment: so why do you say it does it work as you did the same way i did?

Comment: the onChange method is called. But theres not scaling of the drawable inside the imageview.@pskink

Comment: did you try my `IV` custom class? it calls `setImageMatrix` inside `onChange`, doesn't it work? if your code does not work just compare it to my `IV` class

Comment: the way I did it was by defining an object of your interface inside onCreate() which then created the method onChange by itself..sort of like an abstract class. There was an imageview created on  onCreate whose setScaleType was Matrix and inside this onChange method the view.setImageMatrix method was called. Of course, I created an object that was fed through the onTouchMethod for updates of scaling. @pskink. The onChange method was being called this way, but no scaling was taking place on the imageView

Comment: post your code then

Comment: //define a normal image-view and setScaleType to matrix. Create a class that extends draw-able and override onDraw(); Draw circle in middle of screen. Add draw-able to image-view. Create matrix object. Define mListen147 = new MatrixGestureDetector.onMatrixChangedListener(){ override public void OnChange(Matrix matrix){ view.setImageMatrix(matrix)}} Then: create mgDetect = new MatrixGestureDetector(context,matrix,mListen147);  afterwards, feed mgDetect to onTouchMethod and wait for updates. Of course implement the class MatrixGestureDetector before all this @pskink

Comment: see `getIntrinsic*` methods, most likely you return `-1`

Comment: where is the getInstrinsic methods. In MatrixGestureDetector class? @pskink

Comment: Why would I need to measure my ImageView? @pskink Remember, this is an imageview I created like this : ImageView view = new ImageView(this); I didn't create a class that extends ImageView. My view is added to a frame layout with match parent width and height... the view gets a drawable from a custom made class that extends DrawAble.